# Are inputstreams/readers always meant to be closed?

Tags: java, io, stream, sax

When we pass an `InputStream` or a `Reader` to an `InputSource` who/when is the stream/reader is to be closed?
In the example in [saxproject](http://www.saxproject.org/quickstart.html) the streams/readers are not closed.
Why? Am I not supposed to close these streams?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's good practices to close resources when you're done using them (if you created them). I'd say the saxproject sample code is sloppy.

As for the "who" - a heavy-weight resource should generally be closed/freed within the scope that created it (and thus owns it) to avoid ownership confusion.

Comment: But the stream/reader is shared by the sax library and application code, right?So the idea is that it is closed when sax has finished using it?

Comment: No, when you call createXMLReader() the control of the reader is handed over to you. The API documentation doesn't explicitly say so, but that's how I would interpret it, given the name "create...".

Comment: I will give it a while and if no different answer appears I will accept it. +1 from me for now